Apply CSS to last of type of specific class
I need to apply css to the last finding of the .active class <td> element. I am using last-of-type css selector but that is not working. I know I can target the element using nth-child or nth-last-of-type, but the sequence and order is dynamic not static.
Is there any way that can be achieved using CSS only.


tr.row td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 12px;
}

tr.row.active:last-of-type td {
  background: blue;
}
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>1st</td>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row active">
      <td>2nd</td>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row active">
      <td>3rd</td>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row active">
      <td>4th</td>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td>5th</td>
      <td>Row</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



